# Can I call .cs file from form action?

Tags: c#, php, asp.net

There is a code in my site as follows(html page):

```
    <form action="form.php" method="post">
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td>
            <input type="text" class="email1" name="name" maxlength="20" class="bg_in" />
          </td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    <input type="submit" name="posted" value="" class="bg_in2" />
  </form>
```

I want to change it that instead of `action="form.php"` it will be `action="form.cs"`. Is that possible? if so, what should be the method name that catches the action and how do I catch the inputs?

Answer (score 0):

The form is always submitted to the page itself. If you specify an action attribute, it is ignored. If you omit the method attribute, it will be set to method="post" by default. Also, if you do not specify the name and id attributes, they are automatically assigned by ASP.NET

If you select view source in an .aspx page containing a form with no name, method, action, or id attribute specified, you will see that ASP.NET has added these attributes to the form. It looks something like this: